# Vorticity not showing up in Paraview

Tags: visualization, paraview

I have a snapshot of a 3D field whose domain is a cube. I need to visualize the vorticity associated with this field. I am following the approach described by this [video](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwjL5aqm2Pz8AhXLhFwKHRZ0AAAQtwJ6BAg0EAI&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3DZN7hZMZ8iXQ&usg=AOvVaw1Je4YpWXQRqkkqtJQXP_rw) in which the vorticity gets calculated by ParaView.

I followed the procedure but, inside the filter *Compute derivatives* / *Coloring*, I cannot find the vorticity but only the components of the starting field as you can see from the following picture:

[image]

I read that another method is to use the filter for unstructured data but I don't have such a filter.

How should I properly visualize the vorticity?

I am using ParaView 5.10.

Answer (score 0):

In your screenshot, the value for `Vectors` property shows a  `(?)`, meaning that it is not a valid input. You should select an existing vector arrays here.